# Convert into Image PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

Some PDF file content is formatted as text (e.g content is not an image, text can be selected)

How should I convert `PDF Text file` into fully `PDF Image File` programmatically?
I'm using Visual C# 2005 as an editor. Is there any dynamic library to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [ITextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) or [Neevia](http://www.neevia.com/products/dcpro/) Document Converter Pro.

Thanks

Muralidharan T R

Answer (score 1):

[Take a Screenshot](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2007/06/how-to-take-screenshot-in-c.html) of each Page and save them as an Image, then convert/add themn to PDF take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642280/jpg-to-pdf-convertor-in-c-sharp).