# Error while creating pdf usingitext sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this
>   error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(),
>   response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

I am getting this error when i am trying  to create PDF of the page HTML using iTextSharp.

Any one has any idea how to resolve it?

This is my button click event in which i create PDF.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Filename.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            //Render PlaceHolder to temporary stream
            StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            PlaceholderPdf.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(stringWrite.ToString());
            //Create PDF document
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            HTMLWorker parser = new HTMLWorker(doc);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
            doc.Open();

            try
            {
                //Create a footer that will display page number
                //Parse Html
                parser.Parse(reader);

            }
            finally
            {
                doc.Close();
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: refer to this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1392827.aspx

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code... what controls do you have on the page? UpdatePanels? AjaxControlToolkit?

Comment: You might be using response.write, server.transfer or similar within updatepanel; avoid that.
Refer to [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx).

Comment: My page content which i m converting in PDF does not have any update panel. The content is parsed successfully but at the end it breaks don't know where?

Comment: you might be missing catch function...there it may be showing u an actual error

Comment: Ni i do have a catch block.. n error is no thrown here. the eror is thrown on the java script. of some other page

Comment: are you using same code as given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947721/get-the-whole-page-as-a-pdf/19948099#19948099 or some sort of addition is done in it??pls show the addition part....did u have tried doing debug??

Comment: Yes i am using the same code. That was my question only. When I have implemented that in a sample application then its working fine but when i included it in my main project it is throwing this error and rather the HTML is not having the style and css of that page

Comment: if no difference than how could it is possible??....u were asking about image.jpg to have in pdf..did u have tried that?...have a look on namespace present in .cs page may be some is missing there also

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Response.Clear()` at the top of the `Button1_Click()` code?