# JSP/HTML/CSS to PDF generation

Tags: html, css, jsp, pdf

Basically a simple question:
In php you have mpdf/tcpdf etc libraries that convert your HTML/CSS as is into a pdf file.

I have now a JSP page from where i open up a popup JSP including kind of a organizational chart with divs created from HTML/CSS. Is it possible that i can just take this whole popup and convert it somehow into a pdf file -> in chrome you have the option of save as pdf -- and that works it creates a pdf file successfully ! But i want the website to create a pdf itself without browser plugin. Is it possible? Does Java/JSP have such an option to convert pure HTML/CSS to pdf?

Comment: You can get help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947721/get-the-whole-page-as-a-pdf/19948099#19948099

Answer (score 0):

You could use Wkhtmltopdf to convert from HTML to PDF.  https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/