# Converting jpg/Jpeg to pdf in C#

Tags: c#

I want to do a project in C#.I saw several online software which converts jpeg to pdf/doc/docx and vice versa.Now I want to build my own software which will dothe same thing as a hobby project.

Can someone plz guide me from where should i start?

Comment: If you just want to produce a pdf ITextSharp would be a good start.

Comment: Little bit too broad, right? What you tried? What doesn't work? Are you looking for a library? (then SO isn't right place to ask)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good place to start! Break your code down into smaller milestones and get each part working :)

[JPG to PDF Convertor in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642280/jpg-to-pdf-convertor-in-c-sharp)

```
 PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
 doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
 XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
 XImage img = XImage.FromFile(source);

 xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
 doc.Save(destinaton);
 doc.Close();
```