# iTextSharp Can not Convert All HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, html, .net, pdf, itext

Using the sample codes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp) I come up with these codes -

```
var my_html = this.GetmyReportHtml();
    var my_css = this.GetmyReportHtmlCss();

    Byte[] bytes;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER))
        {
            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
            {
                doc.Open();

                try
                {
                    using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(my_css)))
                    {
                        using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(my_html)))
                        {
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        bytes = ms.ToArray();
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\\temp\test.pdf", bytes);
```

PDF has been generated.  However my_html has 6 pages in my case, only half of the content are converted to pdf.

Anyone knows what happened here?  How to know if iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml works properly?

Thanks

Comment: What's inside getMyReportHtml method? Is it taking a html page in your project? I need it actually.

Comment: @nsarchar Yes.  getMyReportHtml gets the whole page.

Comment: how is that getting the html page? Taking them into an array? Can you please share w me?

Comment: @nsarchar I got the page as a giant html string.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem.  In this line of codes -

```
using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER))
```

PageSize.LETTER can not be passed in.

Comment: Hi Guys,  After I removed the PageSize.LETTER, it generated all pages of PDF for me.   But today when I test it again, the problem appears again.  my_html has all the pages available.   But only half of PDF pages are generated.   Anyone knows what is the problem?