# how to convert image to pdf and ms word document C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

i want to develop desktop app to convert images to text than add that text to PDF and ms word document simple c# code can anyone help me i just uploaded the image in picturebox but i can not get it how to to the remaining task

Comment: Google for a c#/.NET pdf library!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPG to PDF Convertor in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642280/jpg-to-pdf-convertor-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks but what about ms word document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use OCR(optical character recognition) librariys
for example

1. TesseractOCR
2. Microsoft Cognitive Services - Computer Vision API
3. EmguCV with TesseractOCR

   image to text with Tesseract OCR sample code
   https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-samples tesseract for c# nuget link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/

You can use it to convert text to pdf file itextsharp https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

You can now convert to the Word file
[How to extract text from MS office documents in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011234/how-to-extract-text-from-ms-office-documents-in-c-sharp)

[image]

Comment: i want to convert text from textbox i don't want to create text file and than convert it. Is it possible?

Comment: text file or text is the same, ocr text returns you back

Comment: okay thanxxxx @mesutpiskin